# Change of default behaviour when connecting to external display: mirror mode

Tags: macos, display, system-settings, mirroring

Some OS generations back the default behavior when a new display was attached was that the screen was mirrored.

I would like to get this behavior back since without it I have to fiddle with the system settings every time I want to give a presentation, since the projector I am connecting with is new to the OS and I have to set up everything.

So question: Is there a plist or something that I can change once and for all?

Answer (score 2):

Just press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> after connecting the display to your Mac and your screen will mirror.

ps. you might have to press <kbd>fn</kbd> as well. This depends on how you've set up your F-keys.

Comment: Thanks! This is great! But having a plist setting would save even pressing these two keys.